# Structure initialization within static method - Code safety

Tags: c++, static

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int length;
}myStruct;

static myStruct getname()
{
    static myStruct name;

    if (name.length == 0)
    {
        name.value = "BLABLA";
            name.length = name.value.size();
    }

    return &name;
}
```

Is this code safe?? i.e can I guarantee that after constructing `myStruct name`, `name.length` will be equal to 0

Comment: Please don't typedef structs in C++. There's also no point in storing the string length twice, and also your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Why do you need the length when you can access name.size() ? Do you really need this struct or is it just a minimal example?

Comment: Guys Come on, this is an example code!!

Comment: why am I getting downvotes?! the question is clear and simple I just want to know if constructing myStruct name, name.length will be equal to 0

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct myStruct {
    string name;
    int length;
    myStruct(string name = "") : name(name), length(name.size()) {} 
};

static myStruct getname() {
    static myStruct name("BLABLA");
    return name;
}
```

Use the constructor initialization list, this is way safer. Here the length is initialized to the size of the name and it defaults to an empty string which has size == 0.

Comment: It would be way safer to remove the `length` data member completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of, since static variables are zero-initialized. However, your code is not thread-safe. It would be better to say `static myStruct name = initName();`, which would be guaranteed to be executed only once.

Since there's also no point in storing the string length twice, your entire code could be simplified to this:

```
static std::string const & getName()
{
    static std::string impl("BLABLA");
    return impl;
}
```

Or even:

```
static const char * const name = "BLABLA";
```

Comment: @Kerek but the structure is static

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `name.length` will be 0.

NOTE: You're returning `&name` which is a pointer to a `myStruct` whilst your code is declared to just return a `myStruct`

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts of "safe" at play here.

The code as it stands is safe, because static variables are initialized to zero.  (*[for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373108/why-are-static-variables-auto-initialized-to-zero)*)

However, I do not consider it "safe" because the initialization is non-obvious.
If another programmer tried to modify this code, they may not realize the importance of having `name.length` initialized to zero, and the fact that initialization is guaranteed by the `static` keyword.

The code as written makes it *look* like initialization is not in play, when in fact it is.
I think at the very least you need to add a comment:

```
/* structure is initialized to all-zeros because it is static */
static myStruct name;
```