# Why does a user-provided default constructor lead to an uninitialized member?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{ // with implicit default constructor
       int number;
};

struct B{
       int number;
       B(){}; // user-provided default constructor
};

int main()
{
    A aa = {};
    B bb = {};

    std::cout << "aa.number: " << aa.number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bb.number: " << bb.number << std::endl;    
}
```

[Running the code online](https://rextester.com/UJG46713)
results in the following output:

```
aa.number: 0
bb.number: 19715
```

Why is bb.number uninitialized? 
I thought that zero initialisation is guaranteed by using ={} ?

Comment: Default initialization of primitive datatypes is not a guarantee of C++ and never was. The design principle is - you don't pay for what you don't use. There's an ample use case for uninitialized memory (think `char[10000]` for reading files into), ergo - it's not zero inited unless you explicitly say so. `int` members in classes are no different in that regard.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev "_Default initialization of primitive datatypes is not a guarantee of C++ and never was._" It is guaranteed that variables with `static`, or `thread_local` storage duration will be zero-initialized.

Comment: Static?? News to me, cite please...

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev You could have done a simple search, about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373108/why-are-static-variables-auto-initialized-to-zero

Comment: That cite is for C, not C++.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev [cppreference.com: zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Sorry about that. C++17 standard draft, section 6.8.3.2.2 ([basic.start.static]): "_If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is zero-initialized._"

Comment: C++17, that explains. I'm old, my bad :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought that zero initialisation is guaranteed by using ={} ?

That is only true if the type is "correct", which `B` is not.  `B bb = {};` will default construct a `B` and your default constructor, `B(){};`, doesn't initialize `number` so no matter what, `number` will never be initialized because that is how your default constructor works.  If you had a "correct" constructor like

```
B() : number(0) {};
// or use
int number = 0;
B(){};
// or even better
int number = 0;
B() = default;
```

Then you'd get zero initialization of `number` when it is default constructed.

This isn't the case with `A` because `A` is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and those come with certain guarantees like zero initialization if an empty *braced-init-list*, technical name for the `{}`, is used.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the type being "correct"?

Comment: @0x5453 Added to the answer.

Comment: I think your second option would be better if you `= default`ed the constructor with the member initialization.

Answer (score 8):

`A` is an *aggregate type*, because it doesn't have any user-provided constructors (and fulfills [a few other requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)).

Therefore `A aa = {};` does *not* call the implicitly generated default constructor. Instead initialization with brace-enclosed initializer lists performs *aggregate initialization*, which for an empty list means that the members are initialized as if by a `{}` initializer, which in turn means for a member of scalar type such as `int` that it will be initialized to zero.

`B` is *not* an aggregate type, because it *does* have a user-provided constructor.

Therefore `B bb = {};` cannot do aggregate initialization and will call the default constructor instead. The default constructor (in either `A` or `B`) does not specify an initializer for the members and so the member is *default-initialized*, which for a fundamental type, such as `int`, means that it will not be set to any value. Its value will remain *indeterminate*.

Accessing the indeterminate value, which your program does, causes *undefined behavior*.

---

If you declare a constructor yourself, then it becomes that constructor's responsibility to initialize all the members appropriately. The rule that `= {}` or `{}` always initializes only holds under the assumption that a user-provided default constructor, if it exists, *does the right thing* in the sense that it provides sensible initializers to all its members and it doesn't have to mean *zero-initialization* necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

`struct B` has a user-provided constructor, so it doesn't get the default constructor that can initialize the members to zero.  Your user-provided constructor replaces that, so you have to do the work yourself.